# What is O(log(n!)), O(n!), and Stirling's approximation?

Tags: time-complexity, big-o

What is `O(log(n!))` and `O(n!)`? I believe it is `O(n log(n))` and `O(n^n)`? Why?

I think it has to do with [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), but I don't get the explanation very well.

Am I wrong about `O(log(n!)` = `O(n log(n))`? How can the math be explained in simpler terms? In reality I just want an idea of how this works.

Comment: `n!` is exactly what it is. Strange notation though...

Comment: @leppie "is exactly what it is". Aahhh.. that's too funny.

Answer (score 113, accepted):

`O(n!)` isn't equivalent to `O(n^n)`. It is asymptotically less than `O(n^n)`.

`O(log(n!))` is equal to `O(n log(n))`. Here is one way to prove that:

Note that by using the log rule `log(mn) = log(m) + log(n)` we can see that:

```
log(n!) = log(n*(n-1)*...2*1) = log(n) + log(n-1) + ... log(2) + log(1)
```

**Proof that** `O(log(n!)) ⊆ O(n log(n))`:

```
log(n!) = log(n) + log(n-1) + ... log(2) + log(1)
```

Which is less than:

```
log(n) + log(n) + log(n) + log(n) + ... + log(n) = n*log(n)
```

So `O(log(n!))` is a subset of `O(n log(n))`

**Proof that** `O(n log(n)) ⊆ O(log(n!))`:

```
log(n!) = log(n) + log(n-1) + ... log(2) + log(1)
```

Which is greater than (the left half of that expression with all `(n-x)` replaced by `n/2`:

```
log(n/2) + log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2) = floor(n/2)*log(floor(n/2)) ∈ O(n log(n))
```

So `O(n log(n))` is a subset of `O(log(n!))`.

Since `O(n log(n)) ⊆ O(log(n!)) ⊆ O(n log(n))`, they are equivalent big-Oh classes.

Comment: Thanks, I don't really get the last part `log(n/2) + log(n/2) + ... + log(n/2) = `floor(n/2)*log(floor(n/2))``. How does `floor(n/2)*log(floor(n/2))` relate to `O(log(n!))` or `O(n log(n))`?

Comment: log(ab)=log(a)+log(b) would be the point when it comes to unwinding the n! into n separate factors, I believe.

Comment: If O(log(n!)) = O(nlog(n)) then O(n!) = O(n^n). When you apply log to both sides of the equation you get O(log(n!)) and O(log(n^n)) = O(nlog(n)) which is the same thing you just proved.

Comment: @kazuoua You can't just apply `log` to both sides of the equation like that. If you could, then you could also argue that `O(n²) = O(n)`, since `O(log(n²)) = O(2log(n)) = O(log(n))`.

Comment: @kazuoua The reason you can't apply `log` to both sides of the equivalence, is because each side is a `set` and sets are not in the domain of the `log` function.

Comment: I just came across this trying to remember why O(n!) = O(n^n).  They are, by the way, equivalent.

You can prove this by taking the limit of n!/n^n = 0 as n goes to infinity. It is 0. The sum of of n!/n^n as n goes to infinity converges to 1.87985. Thus, they are the same complexity class.

Comment: @NickAceves They are not equal classes. `O(n!)` is a strict subset of `O(n^n)`. That "proof" makes no sense. The limit of `n/n^n` as `n` goes to infinity is also `0`; same with the limit of `1/n^n`. Your reasoning would prove that `O(1) = O(n^n)`.

Comment: @NickAceves It is also easy to prove by contradiction that `O(n^n)` is not in `O(n!)` using the definition of big-Oh.

Answer (score 19):

By Stirling's approximation,

```
log(n!) = n log(n) - n + O(log(n))
```

For large n, the right side is dominated by the term n log(n). That implies that O(log(n!)) = O(n log(n)).

More formally, one definition of ["Big O"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) is that f(x) = O(g(x)) if and only if

```
lim sup|f(x)/g(x)| < ∞ as x → ∞
```

Using Stirling's approximation, it's easy to show that log(n!) ∈ O(n log(n)) using this definition.

A similar argument applies to n!. By taking the exponential of both sides of Stirling's approximation, we find that, for large n, n! behaves asymptotically like n^(n+1) / exp(n). Since n / exp(n) → 0 as n → ∞, we can conclude that n! ∈ O(n^n) but O(n!) is not equivalent to O(n^n). There are functions in O(n^n) that are not in O(n!) (such as n^n itself).