# Determine Big-O runtime for these loops

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I am trying to determine the Big-O runtimes for these loops.  I believe the answers I have are correct, but I would like to check with the community.

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 1; i <= n*2; i++ )
   sum++;
```

My answer is O(n)

This is because the loop iterates n x 2 times.  We drop the 2 and are left with n.  Therefore O(n).

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for ( int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2)
      sum++;
```

My answer is O(n lgn)

The outer loop iterates n times.  The inner loop iterates from n down to 0, but only through half of the items.  This works out to be Log base 2 of n.  We drop the 2 and keep log n.  The inner loop (log n) times the outer loop (n), gives us O(n lgn).

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for ( int j = i; j <= n; j += 2)
      sum++;
```

My answer is O(n^2)

This one is easy.  The inner loop and outer loop each iterate n times.  n x n = n^2.  Therefore O(n^2).

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <= n * n; i++)
   for ( int j = 1; j < i; j++ )
      sum++;
```

My answer is O(n^3)

Are my answers correct?  If not, how can I correct them?

Comment: Can you explain how you arrived at your answers, especially the last one?

Comment: @ScottHunter, all my work is written out in pen and paper, but I will try to update the question to include this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only the last one is wrong. It should be O(n⁴).

You can see it this way: substitute `n * n` with `x`. The number of operations will be the usual O(x*(x+1)/2) = O(x²). Now substitute `n * n` back into `x`.

---

**Extra challenge for you.**

You correctly said that:

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for ( int j = n; j > 0; j /= 2)
      sum++;
```

Is O(n log n). But what about this one:

```
int sum = 0;
for ( int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
   for ( int j = i; j > 0; j /= 2)
      sum++;
```

I only changed `j = n` to `j = i`.

Comment: If you give up, the answer is: it's the sum of O(log(i)) for i=1 to n, thus: O(log(1)+log(2)+log(3)+...+log(n)) = O(log(1*2*3*...*n)) = O(log(n!)) [= O(n log n)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118221/what-is-ologn-and-on-and-stirling-approximation).

Comment: Thank you!  This helped me a lot.  I see where I went wrong on the last one.  I guess another way to think about it is inner loop iterates 1+2+3+...+((n(n+1)/2)) times, which equals n^2.  The outer loop also iterates n^2 times.  So when multiplied, you get n^4 times.