# Is O(N!*N) an acceptable big oh complexity class or do I remove the constant and just say O(N!)?

Tags: java, big-o

Is O(N!N) an acceptable big oh complexity class or do I remove the constant and just say O(N!)?

Comment: That isn't a constant.

Comment: So if it was O(N!+N) then the second N would be a constant?

Comment: `O(n!*n)` is rather high complexity. But since there is multiplication you cannot remove second n. But if there was addiction like `o(n!+n)` then n could be omitted since fir big values of n, `n` is not significant compared to `n!`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Big O, how do you calculate/approximate it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it)

Comment: @ivan that’s really an answer, not a comment; please consider converting it

Answer (score 2):

See [What is O(log(n!)) and O(n!) and Stirling Approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118221/what-is-ologn-and-on-and-stirling-approximation), which discusses the relationship between `O(n!)` and `O(n^n)`. This should help you to determine the appropriate big-O when you multiply those by `n`.

The additional `n` in your problem is not a constant, and is not dominated by the `n!`, so it does not disappear from the function when you convert from the actual value of the function to the Big-O (or Big-Theta) asymptotic complexity class of the function.

For Big-O, it's probably sufficient to say `O(n^(n+1))`, but that's not sufficient for Big-Theta.

Here's a related problem involving Big-O and factorials: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/323290/stirlings-approximation

Answer (score 2):

Lets do some algebra ....

```
  N!      =  N x (N - 1) x (N - 2) x ... 1    // by definition

  N! x N  =  N x (N x (N - 1) x (N - 2) x ... 1)

          =  (N + 1 - 1) x (N x (N - 1) x (N - 2) x ... 1)

          =  ((N + 1) x N x (N - 1) x (N - 2) x ... 1) 
              - (N x (N - 1) x (N - 2) x ... 1)

          =  (N + 1)! - N!
```

Now, it is "intuitively obvious"<sup>1</sup> that `O((N + 1)! - N!)` is the same as `O((N+1)!)` ... and this can be proved from first principles.

Also, it is "intuitively obvious" that `O(N!N)` is N times as expensive as `O(N!)` which puts it into a different complexity class.  (Just like `O(N)` and `O(N^2)` are different complexity classes!)

---

But here's the thing.  The `O(N!)` complexity class is clearly problematic for *practical* computations as `N` gets large.  It is substantially worse than simple exponential.

```
  N!   ~=  N^N for large N  // by Stirling's Approximation

  N^N   =  e^(NlogN)

  e^(NlogN) >> e^N for large N
```

So basically, whether you have `O(N!)` or `O(N!N)` you have a big problem ... either way.

---

<sup>1 - Statements like "intuitively obvious" are not proper maths.  Obviously.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

O(n!*n) is rather high complexity. But since there is multiplication you cannot remove second n. But if there was addiction like o(n!+n) then n could be omitted since for big values of n, `n` is not significant compared to `n!`

Comment: To extend the answer: *not significant* - `n! + n < n! + n! = 2n!` take constant `c = 2`, same equivalence class.