# How is log(n!) bounded by Ω(log(n^n))

Tags: big-o

[image]

From what I know, n^n grows faster than n!, so log(n!) is O(log(n^n)) is easy, but how is log(n!) Ω(log(n^n))?

Comment: [Does this help?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8118257/5684257)

Comment: @HTNW definitely! thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is O(log(n!)) and O(n!) and Stirling Approximation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118221/what-is-ologn-and-on-and-stirling-approximation)