# Why is O(log(n)) coming equal to O(log(n!))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, big-o, complexity-theory

While solving the complexity of a code, I found it as O(log(n!)). I know that this can be proven equal to O(n*log(n)). However, can someone tell where this proof is going wrong?

> Theorems used:

- log(ab) = log(a) + log(b)
- O(a+b) = O(max(a,b))

> Proof

```
O(log(n!)) = O(log(n*(n-1)*(n-2)*...*2*1))

           = O(log(n) + log(n-1) + ... )

           = O(max(logn, log(n-1), ...))

           = O(log(n))
```

Can someone tell where I'm going wrong?

Comment: You should not use max in the proof cause it is not upper bound of the sum. Or only max.

Comment: Following your application of max, you could also prove O(n^2) = O(n), because O(n^2) = O(n + n + ... + n) = O(max(n,n,...,n)) = O(n)

Comment: For the record, you can find a clever proof at https://stackoverflow.com/a/8118257/4607733

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot say
O(log(n) + log(n-1) + ... )
= O(max(logn, log(n-1), ...))

This is only true for a constant number of summands. In your case the number depends on **n**.

Otherwise you could also proof

O(n)=O(1+1+1+1+1+...1) = O(max(1,1,1,...))= O(1)

Comment: Oh. So the addition to max rule doesn't apply in case of infinity?