# Big O Notation of the terms f(n) = n*log(n!) and g(n) = 3n*(log n)^(5n)

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have:

- () =  * log(!)
- () = 3 * log(n)<sup>5n</sup>

I must show whether:

- () = Ω(()) or/and
- () = O(())

At first I tried to simplify (). This brings me to: () = 15<sup>2</sup> * log(n)

My next step would be to guess the factorial in (). For this I estimate an upper bound of . So now I can compare the two terms.

I know that: () ≤ O(())

* log() ≤ c * <sup>2</sup> * log(n) 
<sup>2</sup> * log(n) ≤ c * <sup>2</sup> * log(n)

So for c ≥ 1 → () = O(())

But how do I prove this for Ω? Or is my approach for O even right?

Answer (score 1):

You will need [Sterling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation). In short it states that `ln(n!) = n * ln(n) - n + Θ(ln(n))` which directly leads to `Θ(n * ln(n)) = Θ(ln(n!)` See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8118257/812912).

Answer (score 1):

To compare these functions you just need to take a `log` from them and note that `log(n!)` is in `Theta(n log(n))`. Hence, we have the following:

```
log(f(n)) = log(n log(n!)) = log(n) + log(log(n!)) => log(f(n)) is in `Theta(log(n))`

log(g(n)) = log(3n) + log(log(n)^(5n) = log(3n) + 5n log(log(n)) => log(g(n)) is in `Theta(n log(log(n)))`.
```

Therefore, as `log(n)`, `f(n)`, and `g(n)` are an increasing function, we can say that `f(n)` is in `o(g(n))` (little-oh). Consequently, `f(n)` cannot be in `Omega(g(n))`, and definitely `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` (because `Big-O(g(n))` is a subset of `little-o(g(n))`).

Comment: @RoteZora No, sorry, it means that `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` and `f(n)` cannot be in `Theta(g(n))`.

Comment: @RoteZora as I showed, `f(n)` cannot be in `Theta(g(n))`!

Comment: But if `log(n!)` is `θ​(n log(n))` doesn't that equal to `n * log(n!)` being `θ​(n^2 log(n))`? Or is it wrong just do multiply the additionally n into θ?​

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your first comment in time.