# Will both function have same Time Complexity?

Tags: javascript, time-complexity, big-o

Will both these function have O(nlogn) time complexity ?

```
function loop1(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i<arr.length; i++){
        for (let j=i; j<arr.length; j++){
            console.log(arr[j])
        }
    }
}
```

```
function loop2(arr) {
    for (let i = 0; i<=arr.length; i++){
        for (let j=1; j<=Math.log(i); j++){
            console.log(arr[j])
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you describe what those functions do. They seems to have different results, is it intended ?

Comment: @Portevent Yes, I just came across these 2 algos in a book about JavaScript where the Output for both was asked but I could not figure out the time complexity

Comment: I would call the first one `O(n * n)`, as the number of iterations of the inner loop clearly grows in a way proportional to the size of `n`.

Comment: @Pointy yeah got it, the second loop would be O(n * log(n)) ?

Comment: @YRR yes I think so, though as noted it's kind-of a weird thing to do. I suppose there might be a practical use for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

Your first code will run

*n + (n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n(n+1)/2 = O(n<sup>2</sup>)*

iterations (see [arithmetic progression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_progression)).

Your second code runs

*0 + floor(log(1)) + floor(log(2)) + ... + floor(log(n)) <= log(1) + log(2) + ... log(n) = log(n!) = O(n logn)*

iterations (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8118221/what-is-ologn-on-and-stirlings-approximation)).

Notice also that your second code, first iteration, computes `Math.log(0)`, which in javascript returns `-Infinity` so it works for this case, but in mathematics it is not defined.